# Reduce load times by merging cdn files of different modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, cdn

Initially my project was straightforward, it was a simple project that just involved firebase as a backend. But as thing's processed and I started adding more features to the project, more libraries were added to this project (Its a Web App made with Vanilla JS).
Now I have various libraries from CDN's such as Katex,JQuery,Firebase,d3Js,summernote,etc. and this made load times higher for my site. (now at 3s)
But I Don't use all the features from this libraries, so it doesn't make any sense for me to load the entire libraries which are 100s of KB in size.

- So firstly, how do I minify it?
  (I don't want to switch to NodeJS and start using services like webpack, as transitioning to it seems time consuming and lengthy to do especially because this project has grown large and I don't want to sit debugging which features have been ported successfully and which have an issue)
- Secondly, is it possible for me to port this to NodeJS in a way that I could just copy and paste files into the folder and it would work normally and later I could use some module bundler's to minify modules.
  (What I mean is I tried to use stuff like React to port it over, but it seems very tiresome and it seems to better to rewrite the code from scratch rather than trying to port it over. Also it seems to have a different syntax than what I'm used to.)

---

EDIT
I Have Migrated Successfully to using Parcel for all the code shaking and minification, and it seems to minify all the stuff well while not forcing me to change any of the current code and the current load times are far better than they used to.

Comment: if you want to minify it, you need a webpack/rollup or something else to do a tree-shaking. If you just only want to speed it up, split your code out with the 3rd-party resources. and use cdn/service-worker to speed it up.

Comment: Are you configuring caching of the cdn assets?

Comment: @YeXiaoRain is it possible to use webpack/rollup to do tree shaking on entire project? like can it check both javascript,html,css of the project and then get all the dependencies and do the tree shaking? or do I need to modify my current "vanilla" code to something else for it to do that?

Comment: @morganney Im currently loading cdn assets from public cdn providers like jsDelivr, but it takes up lots of bandwidth and increases load time of the website. So im looking for both minifying the current modules which i'm getting from them, and also looking for a way that once it has been loaded it be cached on the user's computer in order to have faster load times.

Comment: I asked this question because i generated a Lighthouse Report and according to it almost 50% of my cdn assets bytes are being unused. so i wanted it to optimise a bit.